# How do I simplify this expression

Tags: exponential-function

I have the expression $$e^{log(3)* log(7)\over log 2}$$

I know it can be simplified to $$3^{log(7)\over log(2)}$$  But I don't know how its done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** $$e^{k \log(a)} = \left(e^{\log(a)} \right)^k = a^k$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that

$$e^{b \log{a}} = a^b$$